# Can grsync incorporate grep options?

Tags: rsync, grsync

I would like to know if options after the command line of `rsync` like `grep`, can be incorporated into `grsync` somehow. For example:

```
rsync -av --delete remote_folder local_folder | grep -E '^deleting|[^/]$'
```